# Dump HANA Database using "SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench"

Tags: hana, sap-cloud-platform

I'd like to get dump of a HANA DB using the browser based "SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench".
I'm especially interessted in exporting:

- the structure of the tables including primary and foreign key constraints
- the data inside the tables

Once I log into the "SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench", I'm able to open the "catalog" and execute SQL commands like e.g. `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;`. This allows me to download the data from one table as a CSV. But is there also something similar to [`pg_dump` in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html), a command that exports both table structure and data as for example a tar-compressed `.sql` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the database which you would like to backup and select `Export`.
Be sure to activate the checkbox `Including data`. I am not sure if it is also necessary to check the `Including dependencies` checkbox.

You get a zip file which contains the sql-commands to create the tables and seperate `data` files which contains the content of the tables. Each table is saved in a seperate directory.

[image: export database in SAP HANA workbench]

Answer (score 0):

The [export](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/20da0bec751910148e69c9668ea3ccb8.html) command seems relevant.
The server will generate .sql files for structure and .csv for data.

If the database is a managed service such as HANA Cloud, you don't have access to the filesystem and should dump the files to an S3 bucket or an azure blob store.

Otherwise, just grab the files from the server box.